# I can't install fastapi to VSC

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, pip, fastapi

While i am trying to install FAST API tools, by writing:

```
(venv) C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi>pip install fastapi[all]

terminal throws me exception error (by the way i upgraded pip to latest version), which is:

ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 338, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 482, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 374, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 214, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 205, in _get_updated_criteria
    self._add_to_criteria(criteria, requirement, parent=candidate)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 201, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 281, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 292, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 546, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 58, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 37, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._prepare_build_backend(finder)
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 57, in _prepare_build_backend
    self.req.build_env = BuildEnvironment()
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Desktop\Kişisel Dökümanlar\PythonWorks\fastapi\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 97, in __init__
    fp.write(
  File "C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in position 174: character maps to < undefined >
```

I need help with that, because I can't use `FAST API` for that error, so that lib doesn't include packages it is supposed to.

Comment: Try these two: configure your terminal to UTF-8 and try rename your folder to not contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

"Kişisel Dökümanlar" contains lots of Turkish special chars such as 'ş', 'ö' and 'ü'. Because of this, you have encoding problem. As a workaround, you can use another directory.